# Найти в одномерном массиве минимальное чётное число и максимальное нечётное число

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста написать программу на питон, которая будет находить в одномерном массиве минимальное чётное число и максимальное нечётное число.
Программа в основном написана, но не получается найти минимальное чётное число.

```
n=int(input("Введите количество элементов, которые будут в списке:"))
b=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    a=int(input("Элемент:"))
    b.append(a)
c=[]
d=[]
for i in b:
    if(i%2==0):
        c.append(i)
    else:
        d.append(i)
c.sort()
d.sort()
count1=0
count2=0
for k in c:
    count1=count1-1
for j in d:
    count2=count2+1
print("Минимальное четное число:",c[count1+1])
print("Максимальное нечетное число",d[count2-1])
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать, что не получилось?

Comment: В основном код написан, но вот не получается найти минимальное чётное число

Comment: Тогда добавьте свои попытки в вопрос.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = int(input("Введите количество элементов, которые будут в списке:"))
b = []
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input("Элемент:"))
    b.append(a)

c = []
d = []
for i in b:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        c.append(i)
    else:
        d.append(i)

c.sort()
d.sort()
print("Минимальное четное число:",c[0])
print("Максимальное нечетное число",d[-1])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё заработало

Comment: Сортировать списки для того чтобы найти минимальное и максимальное числа довольно лишняя работа.

Comment: @Эникейщик согласен, я просто немного изменил код автора